# How can I design my imagination?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

[image]

How can I design/code this program flow?

1. I tried using `CardLayout`, but it isn't satisfying my needs.
2. I try with several `JPanel`, when user clicks a button I change `setVisible()` of the related `JPanel`. But this isn't working or I can't succeed in using it.
3. I plan on using several `JFframe`s (left part is always the same), close and open windows according to user selection. This seems absurd...

So, can you help me find a solution?

Comment: Try using `JTabbedPane` instead.

Comment: Cardlayout seems the correct solution. Why doesn't it satisfy you?

Comment: JTabbedPane's tab item seems small (doesnt seems like a button), I cant enlarge. Cardlayout help me some but this time I cant pass "RecordsFrame" to "ShowingStudentsDetails" :| (Thanks all people edited my post )

Comment: @hakan.erdal Since you are controlling when a "card" is displayed, why can't you pass the `RecordsFrame` to `ShowingStudentsDetails`?

Comment: Ok @MadProgrammer, I think I need more research.Then ask again my problem.

Comment: @hakan.erdal Consider having a look at [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for more design ideas

Comment: thanks everyone.. I started the learning cardlayout from wrong examples and wrong codes.Now I learn about it more. thanks everyone is encouraged me. (i hope you understand me, my english isnt good)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I made.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;


public class Imagination extends JFrame {

    private JPanel [] contentPanes ;
    private JPanel buttonsPanel, stuffPanel ;
    private GridLayout layout ;
    private JButton [] consecutiveButtons ;

    Imagination() {

        layout = new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 1);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        contentPanes = new JPanel[3];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < contentPanes.length ; i++ ) {

            contentPanes[i] = new JPanel(layout);
            contentPanes[i].setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

        }
        addToAllPanes();

        buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5));

        consecutiveButtons = new JButton[3];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < consecutiveButtons.length ; i++) {

            consecutiveButtons[i] = new JButton("Sample Button "+i);
            buttonsPanel.add(consecutiveButtons[i]);
            //We will set the name of the button so that
            //we can change the panels
            consecutiveButtons[i].setName(i+"");
            consecutiveButtons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    consecutiveButtonActionPerformed(e);

                }

            });

        }

        stuffPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 5));
        stuffPanel.add(contentPanes[0]);

        setSize(450, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(buttonsPanel);
        add(stuffPanel);

        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Imagination i = new Imagination();
        i.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void addToAllPanes() {

        for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i ++) {

            contentPanes[0].add(new JLabel("A Sample Label"));
            contentPanes[0].add(new JTextField("A Sample Text Field"));
            contentPanes[1].add(new JLabel("Demo Label"));
            contentPanes[1].add(new JTextField("A Sample Text Field"));
            contentPanes[2].add(new JLabel("Stack"));
            contentPanes[2].add(new JTextField("Overflow"));

        }

    }

    private void consecutiveButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(b.getName());
        stuffPanel.removeAll();
        stuffPanel.add(contentPanes[id]);
        stuffPanel.repaint();

    }

}
```

I made three buttons and three panel using arrays and added them into two different panels in the main JFrame.
All the buttons are added in one panel and the panel containing the JTextFields and JTextLabels in another one.
To control what panels are shown when a button is clicked, i set the button's name and add a common action listener to it. In which I did remove all the components and add the required panel.
Then I call repaint() so that it shows at the time when the button is pressed.

**I made this as a hint to your answer. If you think you found your answer, then please accept**